# accessing current redux state in monaco editor action run function

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, monaco-editor

I have a monaco editor instance, and I add an action for the Ctrl+S Keys.

```js
const addActions = (editor: editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor) => {
        editor.addAction({
            id: "save-element-action",
            label: "Save Element",
            keybindings: [KeyMod.CtrlCmd | KeyCode.KEY_S],
            precondition: undefined,
            keybindingContext: undefined,
            contextMenuGroupId: "navigation",
            contextMenuOrder: 1.5,

            // @param editor The editor instance is passed in as a convinience
            run: function (ed) {
                // TODO: saveElement is called but doesnt work yet because expressionEditorState is empty (Closure??)
                saveElement();
            },
        });
    };
```

in the saveElement function i want to access some state from my redux store

```js
    const saveElement = (editor?: editor.ICodeEditor) => {
        if (expressionEditorState.elementContent === undefined || expressionEditorState.elementContent === "") {
            dispatch(createErrorAction("No content for element"));
            return;
        }


        dispatch(createSaveElementAction(user, expressionEditorState.elementContent, expressionEditorState.elementMetaData));
    };
```

the expressionEditorState is the same as the initial state (so empty).
The setup of the state is down with a custom hook and the useSelector hook.

How can i access the current state of redux in the run function of a monaco action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone is following up...
the solution is to use thunks (see redux-thunks). so i rewrote saveElement as thunk and just dispatch it.

```
dispatch(saveElement())
```

Comment: What was the reason that thunk is needed?

Comment: The reason was that the state got copied when adding the action. 
To delay the fetching of the current state, thunks are used for dispatching async actions and to get a valid, current state from the redux store. (see thunks documentation for more infos)